# Vim: yank an entire environment of Tex file

Tags: vim, latex, copy-paste, environment, yank

I am using vim with latex-suite to edit my document and sometimes need to copy an entire environment (from \begin{...} to \end{...}). For example, I want to copy this part

```
\begin{align*}
  \sigma &\rightarrow A | B | C | ABC \\
  A &\rightarrow a | \varepsilon \\
  B &\rightarrow b | \varepsilon \\
  C &\rightarrow c | \varepsilon
\end{align*}
```

Whenever I need to do that, I have to move to the begin tags, count the number of line and enter the yank command (6yy in the case of the above example).

My question is:

1. Is there any faster way to do this job which is similar to yank an entire tag in html or xml file (yit, yat)?
2. If there isn't, could you please show me how can I create my own command to do this in vim?

Comment: Maybe you can put your cursor on `align` press `*` then `N^vnn$` to select the 6 lines?

Comment: Thank you @Lopezo for your quick reply. But this is not what I am looking for. Because it is still slow and slower than my current approach. BTW, when I mentioned "count the number", I didn't mean that I manually count them but I utilized "relative line number" by adding "set rnu" in vimrc file so I can see how many lines I have to yank immediately.

Comment: I can think of a custom text-object. but we need to write that and I am not an expert on that. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to use [vim-textobj-latex](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex) plugin which gives you some new text object. Specifically the `ae` and `ie` text objects for "an environment" and "inner environment".

Note: vim-textobj-latex plugin relies on [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user)